# Rails - Route for merged objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To create a combined timeline, I merged two different objects like so `@new_object = @foo + @bar`. I'm able to retrieve the details of each of the objects' attributes using a block in the index page.

```
<% @new_object.each do |obj| %>
  <%= obj.name %>
  <%= obj.email %>
<% end %>
```

I would like to know how to link_to each of these items linking them to their show page. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: We need more information to help you. What are that object like? Are those ActiveRecord instances?

Comment: @roman.brodetski yes, they are both AR instances and they both belong to the user. Since they are two different AR objects, both have object ids from 1 to n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you merged @foo and @bar and both are unalthered since they were retrieved from activerecord you can use:

```
if obj.class == Foo
  link_to "foo", foo_path(obj)
elsif obj.class == Bar
  link_to "bar", bar_path(obj)
end
```

As the routes are helpers and the required param is the object id.

Comment: thanks for that insight. But, how do I differentiate between foo and bar? Since they are two different AR objects, both have object ids from 1 to n.

Comment: What's @new_object? an Array? If its an array you will have to create a conditional or use a redirect in the controller. Edited to show a possible solution.

Comment: the quotes are a problem I guess. "Foo" & "Bar" didn't work. But without quotes, Foo and Bar in the conditionals worked. Thanks!